# Opening any text/doc file for editing using Javascript/DOJO/ or based framework click event and Java

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

Tried using this, did not work, error is coming as access to file denied:

```
window.open("file:///C://Users//Knightrider//Desktop//data/abcd.txt");
```

also tried this:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                            }
                            else
                            {// code for IE6, IE5
                                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                            }
                            xmlhttp.open("GET","file:///C://Users//Knightrider//Desktop//data/abcd.txt",false);
                            xmlhttp.send();
                            xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Please help me out. hope the information is enough for understanding the issue..

Answer (score -1):

Did it using backend(Java code) with the click event by invoking a servlet.

Thanks for the suggestions...

```
using protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String data = request.getParameter("data");
        System.out.println(data);
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = runtime.exec("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe C:\\abcd\\Desktop\\New folder\\openit.txt");
    }
```

Comment: This does not open the same file though, unless both client and server are on the same machine. If I'm on computer A, and the Java code runs on computer B, it will open the `openit.txt` file on computer B, not on my computer. Since you're working with servlets, I'm pretty sure you don't expect the clients to be running their own webcontainer, or is it?

Comment: @DimitriM file is itself located at server. and the work I am currently doing is associated with server side only.

Comment: as I am building a tool for which both client and server must be on the same machine